# How to initialize a list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How can I initialize a `System.Collections.Generic.List` of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` objects using Collection Initializers?

Comment: When asking a question, it's always a good idea to show what you've tried and what went wrong. In this case, it's not clear whether you know how to use collection initializers to a) initialize a list; b) initialize a dictionary. If you know both of those, combining them is easy. If you don't know one of them, *that's* what your question should be about. In this case, it's not really clear why you would ask the question and self-answer... it's not a question which is likely to come up, IMO.

Comment: While it's fine to add your own question and answer, it *isn't* fine to just keep adding endless permutations of answered scenarios. The answer to "how to initialize a list of dictionaries" is to look at the questions for "how to initialize a list" and "how to initialize a dictionary". There's nothing special about a list of dictionaries in particular.

Comment: Hi, Luaan. I understand that there's nothing special for you, probably used to c# semantics, but defnitely it's not the same. Dictionary is essentially different from List<Dictionary<T,T>>. So, I strongly disagree of your moderation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> listaDeDicionarios = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
{
    new Dictionary<string,object>()
    {
        {"chave1","valor um"},
        {"chave2","dois"},
        {"chave3",true}
    },
    new Dictionary<string,object>()
    {
        {"chave4",4},
        {"chave5",DateTime.Now},
        {"chave6",long.MaxValue},
        {"chave7","..."}
    },
    new Dictionary<string,object>()
    {
        {"chave8","utf string áéí / &url"},
        {"chave9",null},
        {"chave10",String.Empty},
        {"chave11",new List<string>(){"aaa","bbb","ccc","oh my god, it's a miracle!"}}
    }
};
```

Comment: You should edit the question and add this code to it.

Comment: @maniak1982: Why? Answering your own question is perfectly fine and encouraged on SO.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes, that looks like a list of dictionaries to me!

Comment: It wasn't clear whether it was the answer or his existing code.  It's not marked as the answer, after all.

Comment: @maniak1982, you cannot mark your own as an answer before (I believe) 24 hours.

Comment: Hi, all. The goal was, only to share some knowledge, indeed. If I had that question, I believe that others could have too. When the regular time restriction expire, I'll check my own answer.  Unless some better answer appears :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 6.0 you can use:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [1] = "Pankaj",
    [2] = "Pankaj",
    [3] = "Pankaj"
};
```